# Valuation of a root smaller than valuation of a polynomial

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, valuation-theory, class-field-theory

> Let  $(K,|\cdot|)$  be  a  complete  discretely  valued   field, where $|\cdot|$ is a non-archimedean absolute value (or multiplicative valuation).   Fix  an  algebraic  closure $\bar{K}$ of $K$. We also denote by $|\cdot|$ the unique absolute value on $\bar{K}$ extending the one on $K$.  On the polynomial ring $K[T]$ we define the Gauss norm:  for $P(t)=a_n t^n+a_{n-1} t^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0 \in K[t]$, let $||P(t)||:=\max\{|a_0|,|a_1|,\ldots |a_n|\}$.
>
> Consider a monic polynomial $f\in K[t]$ and let $\alpha\in \bar{K}$ be a root of $f$. Show that $|\alpha|\le ||f||$

Now it is clear that if $\displaystyle f(t)=t^n+\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}c_it^i$, then
$$|\alpha^n|=\displaystyle |\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}c_i\alpha^i|\le \max\{|c_i \alpha^i|\}$$
Hence for some $i_o\in \{1,2,...,n-1\}$, we have that $|c_{i_0}|^{\frac{1}{n-i_0
}}\ge |\alpha|$, hence if $|\alpha|\ge 1$, we're done.

However, for the case $|\alpha|< 1$, I am not able to prove this. Also, I am in fact getting the opposite inequality when say $f$ is the minimal monic irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$, because say $f=(x-\alpha)(x-\sigma_2(\alpha))...(x-\sigma_n(\alpha))$, then $|\sigma_i(\alpha)|=|\alpha|$ and 
$$|c_{n-j}|=|\sum \sigma_{\tau(1)}(\alpha)\sigma_{\tau(2)}(\alpha)...\sigma_{\tau(n)}(\alpha)|\le \max| \sigma_{\tau(1)}(\alpha)\sigma_{\tau(2)}(\alpha)...\sigma_{\tau(n)}(\alpha)|=|\alpha|^j<|\alpha|$$
if $j>1$, so the only chance for the inequality to remain true is if $|\alpha|=|c_{n-1}|$, and I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: The Gauss norm of a monic polynomial is always $\geq 1$ due to $a_n=1$.

Comment: Wow, what an idiot I can be at times. I forgot that 1 is a coefficient as well :)